# Python Django "ImportError: No module named hashcompat"

Tags: python, django, importerror

I'm learning python + Django by reading 《beginning django e-commerce》， after I have installed django-db-log, when running $python manage.py runserver, there is a problem.

```
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function wrapper at 0x02C28DB0>

 Traceback (most recent call last): 
  File "D:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 93, in wrapper fn(*args, **kwargs) 
  File "D:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 92, in inner_run self.validate(display_num_errors=True) 
  File "D:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 308, in validate num_errors = get_validation_errors(s, app) 
  File "D:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\validation.py", line 34, in get_validation_errors for (app_name, error) in get_app_errors().items(): 
  File "D:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\loading.py", line 166, in get_app_errors self._populate() File "D:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\loading.py", line 75, in _populate self.load_app(app_name) 
  File "D:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\loading.py", line 96, in load_app models = import_module('.models', app_name)
  File "D:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\utils\importlib.py", line 35, in import_module __import__(name) 
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\djangodblog\models.py", line 9, in <module> 
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\djangodblog\manager.py", line 23, in <module> 
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\djangodblog\helpers.py", line 5, in <module>

ImportError: No module named hashcompat
```

Comment: Sounds like you've installed new django on top of the previous one. Try uninstalling/installing django.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are referring to an outdated manual. Module `hashcompat` was removed in Django 1.6, as you can read [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/internals/deprecation/#id3).

Either install an older Django version (1.5 or previous) or get a more recent textbook. You can also manually fix your code by using Python builtins as advised in the removal notice, but for a beginner can be sort of a hassle :)

Answer (score 6):

I solved it using `hashlib`. I just added:

```
try:
    from hashlib import sha1 as sha_constructor
except ImportError:
    from django.utils.hashcompat import sha_constructor
```

Answer (score 0):

[hashcompat is already deprecated](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/20475) in django 1.6, it is better to use hashlib instead

Answer (score -1):

If you are still following that, the `django` version used in the book is `1.1` and if you are using higher version of `django`, then try removing the `djangodblog` from the app list in the `setting.py` file. It should work.